# VueJs and Laravel how do I pass a mounted data to the blade file?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, mustache

I need to get the var `year_target_progress` to my html, because I need to use it again in a `style="width: @{{ year_target_progress }}%"` but it's giving the result of the value assigned before the axios call, I have have to calculate it with a value that I get from the axios call.
Thank you in advance guys.

I have this in my blade:

```
 <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
    @{{ year_target_progress }}%</div>
```

This in my vuejs:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        delivery: 0,
        max_no: 0,
        max_in_month: 0,

        max_no_order: 0,
        max_in_month_orders: 0,
        year_target_progress: 0,
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.year_target_progress = 11;
        //prima richiesta per grafico vendite/guadagni
        axios
            .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/statistics/${user_id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                
                let ordersPerMonth = [];
                let orders = response.data;
                this.max_in_month = 0;
                let today = new Date();
                let current_month = today.getMonth()+1;
                let current_year = today.getFullYear();
                let last_year = current_year - 1;
                let current_month_revenue = 0;
                var current_year_revenue = 0;
                let year_target = 1000;

                for (let i = 1; i <= current_month; i++) {

                    let ordersSum = 0;

                    orders.forEach((element) => {

                        if (i == parseInt(element.created_at.substr(5, 2)) ) { 
                            if( current_year == parseInt(element.created_at.substr(0, 4)) ) {
                                //per il costo di delievery wtf this shit gives me some bug if I comment it
                                element.total_price -= this.delivery;
                                ordersSum += element.total_price;

                                //get current month value 
                                if( i === current_month){
                                    current_month_revenue = ordersSum;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    //get highest income in a month
                    if (this.max_in_month < ordersSum) {
                        this.max_in_month = ordersSum
                    }

                    
                    ordersPerMonth.push(ordersSum);
                    
                    //sum current year value
                    if(ordersSum > 0)
                    current_year_revenue += ordersSum;
                }

                this.year_target_progress = Math.floor((100 * current_year_revenue) / year_target);

                //max value on y axis - round up to multiple of 10
                this.max_no = Math.round((this.max_in_month + 10 / 2) / 10) * 10;

            //dati in cards
            document.getElementById('month_record').innerHTML = this.max_in_month;
            document.getElementById('current_month_revenue').innerHTML = current_month_revenue;
            document.getElementById('current_year_revenue').innerHTML = current_year_revenue;
            document.getElementById('year_target').innerHTML = year_target.toLocaleString();

            //get the chart from
            let ctx = document.getElementById('myAreaChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

        })
        .catch((er) => {
            alert("Can't load gross revenue chart");
        });
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong, everything else works.

Comment: Read here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles you should be able to do:  `:style={width: year_target_progress + '%'}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it, using this method. It was much easier that I thought

```
document.getElementById('year_target_progress').innerHTML = this.year_target_progress;
                document.getElementById('year_target_progress_style').style.width = this.year_target_progress + '%';
```